# React Native: styling props.children

Tags: javascript, react-native

Let's imagine I have a Button Component. I can import it from different screens and it behaves independently. I can give it different children (text, image, text + icon, icon etc.).

This would look like something like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import theme from '$/theme';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  text: {
    fontFamily: 'Nunito',
    color: 'white',
  },
  icon: {
    color: 'grey',
  }
});

export default (props) => (
  <TouchableOpacity {...props} style={styles.button}>
    {props.children}
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Then

```
// I want to be able to do either without having to style Text/Icon each time
const button1 = <Button><Text>Click</Text></Button>
const button2 = <Button><Icon name="back" /></Button>
```

I want to define the style for icon, text and so on directly in the Button Component, right? Is it possible to pass the `styles.text` variable to the Text component when present in children? Idem for icon, image and so on?

I don't feel like having to fulfill the children style every time is a good practice. I could however use `<Button text={'Click'} />` syntax then play if/else statements but I am not fond of passing attributes for the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass text or icon as props to your `Button` Component

```
export default (props) => (
  <TouchableOpacity {...props} style={styles.button}>
    {props.title && <Text style={styles.text}>{props.title}</Text>}
    {props.icon && <Icon name={props.icon} />}
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Alternatively create `ButtonText` and `ButtonIcon` components.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `React.cloneElement`

```
export default (props) => (
  <TouchableOpacity {...props} style={styles.button}>
    {this.renderChildren()}
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

renderChildren() {
    return this.props.children.map(children => {
        return React.cloneElement(children, {style: { color: 'grey', fontFamily: 'cochin' }});
    })
}
```

But that is if you want use the same style regardless of type of component. It will turn both passed down icon and text grey.